# ¿Cómo mantener el foco de un botón después de enviar el formulario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Me pregunto cómo mantener el foco de un botón en *x* color, ya que después de que se envía se refresca la página.

Tengo dos botones uno verde y uno rojo, al seleccionar rojo se carga un form lo mismo pasa con el verde, y como el verde es el primero cuando se está en el botón rojo y se envía se cambia al verde por default ¿cómo hacer para que se mantenga?

Estoy ocupando esta función para cambiar los colores al hacer clic:

Estos son los botones en bootstrap el primero por default es verde

```js
function ocultar(){
 document.getElementById('div2').style.display="none";
 document.getElementById('div1').style.display="block";
 document.getElementById('uno').style.background="#9BC53D";
 document.getElementById('dos').style.background="none";
};

function mostrar(){
 document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
 document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
 document.getElementById('uno').style.background="none";
 document.getElementById('dos').style.background="#E55934";
};

function color1(){
 document.getElementById('uno').style.background="green";
};
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-default active btnsl" id="uno" onClick="ocultar();">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnone" value="entrada">div1
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default btnsl" id="dos" onClick="mostrar();">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="btntwo" value="salida">div2
</label>
```

Comment: Puedes usar AJAX para enviar los formularios.

Comment: Gracias @Shaz ya la aplique con ajax, saludos

Comment: @J.wink ¿solucionaste ya el problema? Si sí, publica una respuesta con cómo lo hiciste